# How to refresh my RecyclerView list when searchview is cleared?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-cardview

When a Search query text is entered, I filter my card items in the `RecyclerView` and display them on top. However, when all the text is cleared, for some reason, the list does not go back to the original state. How to refresh my `RecyclerView` list? The code below should give you a better idea.

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<Number> filteredModelList = filter(numbers, newText);
        Log.v("App", newText + ", " + numbers.size() + ", " + filteredModelList.size());
        adapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
        list.scrollToPosition(0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (newText.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            try{
                Log.e("SEARCH VIEW", "I CAN ENTER HERE"); //But the list doesn't refresh
                adapter.animateTo(numbers);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.scrollToPosition
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Caught Exception", e.toString());
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is problematic when no item matched the search - then the screen is just blank with no cards, and the "X" button on the `SearchView` is not visible either. When the X is visible, and I touch it, the list goes back to its original state. As a second question, is there a way to always display the close icon ("X")?

Comment: post `filter` and `animateTo` method please

Comment: Hi, I am not allowed to post those methods. However, as in the question, I am entering the condition [f (newText.equalsIgnoreCase("")){] - and I need to refresh my view there. How to do that?

Comment: so it's hard to help. check that you don't remove item with callByRefrence from those method, check you return correct data from filter method with an empty string. you need debug it to find what is the problem

Comment: write a **generic** adapter for a `RecyclerView` (similar to `ArrayAdapter` for normal `ListViews`), then in the future, you will not have to write this filtering code again and again each time you need a new "filtering recyclerview"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you have a method which loads data into your RecyclerView, so what you do, you call back again that method in the IF statement, like :  when the `newText`length is **equal** to `zero` , Do something ......

**Below is the algorithm : .**

```
if (newText.length() == 0){    
    //Reload the data Again , use the existing  method you have of loading data in the RecyclerView .
}
```

If you have some problems , just post again your code loading data in the `RecyclerView` and I show it to you again.

Comment: possible edit for above answer:  should "newText.length" be "newText.length()"?

Answer (score 0):

When You Apply Filter on Array so only Search Record available in Array And Then you  clear a search text that time array is no value ...

so you make one temp array and store original array and apply filter on temp array and add to main array and set to listview when you remove all search text add temp array in main array and set to adapter.

Note:- always apply filter on tamp array and add result in main array and set to adapter

i hope this help you....

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){  //Show all data 
      adapter.animateTo(numbers);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      return ;
    }
     //Do Filter
}
```